# Search view filter Sqlite Android

Tags: java, android

My search view can filter text on list view but i filter the data on search view click on item and the data keep show me the same data cannot filter on sqlite. i miss something or less query or need link anything?

```
    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
           Ar_adapter.getFilter().filter(s);



            return false;
        }
    });


    ArrayList arrayList = appointmentList;
    ArrayList<String> title2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int x = 0; x < arrayList.size(); x++) {
        hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) arrayList.get(x);
        Log.i("HashMap 1 Value: ", hashMap.get("name"));
        Log.i("HashMap 2 Value: ", hashMap.get("id"));
        title2.add(hashMap.get("name"));
    }

    Ar_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_listview, title2);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listActivity);
    lv.setAdapter(Ar_adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int u, long l) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
    String lstr= String.valueOf(l);
    i.putExtra("id",lstr);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

}